# Passing an Variable from one PHP File to another

Tags: php

I'm working on an image resizer, to create thumbnails for my page. The resizer works on principle of include a DIRECT link to the image. But what I want to do is put in the PHP Variable in the URL string, so that it points to that file and resizes it accordingly.

My code is as follows :

```
<img src="thumbnail.php?image=<?php echo $row_select_property['image_url']; ?>
```

Image Resize :

```
 <?php 
  // Resize Image To A Thumbnail

  // The file you are resizing 

  $image = '$_GET[image_url]'; 

  //This will set our output to 45% of the original size 
  $size = 0.45; 

   // This sets it to a .jpg, but you can change this to png or gif 
   header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 

   // Setting the resize parameters
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image); 
   $modwidth = $width * $size; 
   $modheight = $height * $size; 

   // Creating the Canvas 
   $tn= imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight); 
   $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image); 

   // Resizing our image to fit the canvas 
   imagecopyresized($tn, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height); 

    // Outputs a jpg image, you could change this to gif or png if needed 
    imagejpeg($tn); 
    ?>
```

What I am trying to do is pass on the variable "image=" to the Thumbnail script. At the moment I am passing it through the URL string, but it doesnt  seem to load the graphic.

I'll try expand on this more, should you have questions as I am finding it a little difficult to explain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. you can't pass variables between files. 2. there is no `image_url` paramter in your query string. 3. `'$_GET[image_url]'` literal contains string `$_GET[image_url]` in it, which is pretty useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change  it

```
 $image = '$_GET[image_url]';
```

to

```
 $image = $_GET['image'];
```

Comment: You could use ` $image = "$_GET[image_url]";` instead, not that it's a good idea but the difference between " and ' is that if using " embedded variables are expanded but with ' it's a literal string and no variable substitution will take place.

Comment: make sure you have a new PHP(>5.2 => has [filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.installation.php)) otherwise $_GET can be very dangerous.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect at least part of the problem is that your existing...

```
$image = '$_GET[image_url]';
```

...line is creating a text string, rather than getting the contents of the 'image_url' query string. Additionally, your passing in the image name as "?image=" in the query string, so you should simply use "image", not "image_url".

As such, changing this to...

```
$image = $_GET['image'];
```

...should at least move things along.

Answer (score 3):

```
$image = '$_GET[image_url]';
```

should be

```
$image = $_GET['image'];
```