# Passing variable from php to php

Tags: php, variables

I was wondering how to send a php variable from one server to another php script on another server?

I have 2 php scripts on 2 different server and one must send vars to the other.
I've been searching with little luck. 
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: How would these scripts be triggered/run/activated/communicating to begin with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing an Variable from one PHP File to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804440/passing-an-variable-from-one-php-file-to-another)

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve that using `curl` and sending the variable as a GET value.

Something like this:

```
$data = "data you want to send";
$data = urlencode($data);
$url = "http://example.com?data=" . $data;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Let's assume `$data = "foobar"`

Doing the above from a PHP script would be the same as someone visiting `http://example.com?data=foobar` from a browser.

You could obviously send it to any script using the url:

`http://example.com/yourscript.php?data=foobar`

At `yourscript.php` you can get the data at `$_GET['data']`, do some input validation to ensure it is being sent from your script and not from someone else via a browser (more on that later) and then proceed with your script.

For this to work, `yourscript.php` will have to reside in the `public html` folder of youtr webhost so it is accessible to your other script.

**SECURITY**

Whether you are passing the data over `GET` or `POST`, someone else can send (possibly malicious) data to your script as well. Thus, when `yourscript.php` receives data, there needs to be a way for it to ensure you are the sender of the script. An easy way to achieve this is: decide on any arbitrary number known only to you, say, 12.

Concatenate the number with the data you are passing and calculate the md5 hash and send it as another get variable.

In this case, you would calculate `md5("12foobar")`

and the URL would be: `http://example.com/yourscript.php?data=foobar&auth=hash`

When `yourscript.php` receives the data, it calculates the same hash (using the number 12, known to no one else) and if the hash it calculates matches with `$_GET['auth']`, you can be sure you sent the data.

If someone tried to imitate you and send data, they would not know how you calculate the hash, and would thus send the wrong hash.

**PS**

Another way to ensure rock solid security, would be to just check the IP address of the user-agent at `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. If it is the IP address of the webhost where your other script resides, then you know it is you. 
*I haven't thought this method through, so there might be some loopholes.*

Answer (score 1):

You can do that either using GET query strings (`second_php?var=value`) or using a curl connection with POST method and then send your data over POST.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [SOAP](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php). It's used for remote function calls and it brings you little more overhead than just calling http requests, but it also brings you guarantee that remote function will be executed (or will cause error), it will directly return whatever datatype you need and I believe that's what this technology was developed for :)